# Get screenshots window via node js on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, screenshot

I understand that node js for making screenshots in Windows is not the best way, but I have such a special task. The task is, so that I can make a screenshot of a specific window, even if it is not active.
  I have installed ImageMagick from the [official site](http://www.imagemagick.org)(ImageMagick-7.0.5-9-Q16-x64-dll.exe) and tried enter into the PowerShell:

```
magick import my_screenshot.jpg
```

but I get this error:

```
import: delegate library support not built-in '' (X11) @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/1294.
```

This means that there is not any `delegate library`, but that's just how I can install it, I did not find it.

What can I do to make ImageMagick work?

You can also offer your solutions for the make screenshot.

On the advice of @emcconville, I tried so `magick convert screenshot: my_screenshot.jpg`, but that's what happened:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcTmp.jpg)

Comment: The `import` utility is more for [X windows system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System). Try `magick convert screenshot: my_screenshot.jpg`

Comment: @emcconville so thank you for your answer, I tried so. The screenshot was created, but when I opened it I saw some distortion of my screen, and not a real screenshot of my screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using node.js you could use a package to take a screenshot. 
[screenshot-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/screenshot-node) works for me on windows 10 with no other dependencies.

This takes a fullscreen screenshot.

```
const screenshot = require('screenshot-node');

screenshot.saveScreenshot(0, 0, 0, 0, "image.png", (err) => {
    if(err) console.log(err);
}
```